Install tensorflow in Debian 11: Operation not permitted
I am trying to install tensorflow on a linux server running Debian 11, with python version 3.11. The installation succeeds using pip install tensorflow, however when I run:
import tensorflow as tf
from python, I get 'Operation not permitted' with no other details. A bit lost, appreciate any suggestions.
Updated below with other relevant information:
I attempted to install tensorflow in a conda environment using the following steps. First I connect to the server using X2go client. then I open a new terminal window and run:
conda create -n tf_env python=3.11
conda activate tf_env
pip install tensorflow
python3

Then in Python I run:
import sys
print(sys.path)

['', '/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python311.zip', '/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11', '/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/home/m.gordon/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages', '/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages']
import tensorflow as tf

then it prints 'Instruction non permise' (the language of the server is French), and exits python.
Other details:
The system is a shared linux server - I don't have admin permissions, but IT has also tried and gotten the same results. I can import other packages. For example from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score works fine. PYTHONPATH has not been explicitly set. Conda version is 24.1.2. uname -a outputs:
Linux pse-srv-calcul 5.10.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-3 (2023-07-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Tensorflow installed files are:
/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/bin/import_pb_to_tensorboard
/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/bin/saved_model_cli
/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/bin/tensorboard
/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/bin/tf_upgrade_v2
/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/bin/tflite_convert
/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/bin/toco
/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/bin/toco_from_protos
/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow-2.16.1.dist-info/*
/home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/*

within the /tensorflow folder,
file /home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so.2

returns: libtensorflow_framework.so.2: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[md5/uuid]=ca3553bc4ddc370890a646e5c0e844f9, with debug_info, not stripped
file /home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so.2

libtensorflow_cc.so.2: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[md5/uuid]=673df0f0fcf17dfff02e01ad45e3d5ef, with debug_info, not stripped

With no further details, there is really no way to say what's wrong here. At the very least please [edit] to reveal exactly what you installed how and where, your PYTHONPATH and sys.path, and other pertinent details.

How exactly are you running Python when you get the error? Is the sys.path you got identical in the scenario where you get the error? The symtoms suggest that you are simply not inside the active virtual environment.

This seems to indicate that you have installed TensorFlow for the wrong architecture. Can you tell us the file names of the installed files? (Also probably [edit] the question to include the details from your previous comments, and delete those comments. Your question should be self-contained, and comments should only be used to discuss how to improve the post.) Probably also include the output of uname -a at the shell prompt. I'm guessing there is a Conda configuration error at the bottom of this but I'm not familiar enough with it to tell you where to look exactly.

Thanks for the update. Is that to say /home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/* is empty or does not exist? Anything in /home/m.gordon/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload? I'm mainly looking for confirmation that the binaries are not actually amd64-compatible.

site-packages/tensorflow/ and /lib-dynload/ both have a number of files in them. Anything in particular I should look for? One potentially interesting thing is that libtensorflow_cc.so.2 and libtensorflow_framework.so.2 in the site-packages/tensorflow/ folder do not seem to have execute permissions - seems like could this be the issue?

They don't need them (I don't think) but the file names and/or the output of file would perhaps be useful, in particular if they indicate MacOS or Windows etc binaries instead of your platform.

updated above with this info

Since you get the "illegal instruction" message (in french), that means tensorflow is using CPU instructions that your CPU does not support, like AVX, finding a tf version wtihout those instructions or building from source would fix the issue.

this makes sense - it is a pretty old server. If you want to add this as an answer I will accept it. Otherwise I can delete the post as there seem to be others addressing the illegal instructions issue. Looks like the confusion was my poor french translation.
